# How to chage the color of shapes with easeljs

Tags: javascript, html, events, createjs, easeljs

```js
function initCircles() {
  circles = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var circle = new createjs.Shape();
    var r = 7;
    var x = window.innerWidth * Math.random();
    var y = window.innerHeight * Math.random();
    var color = colors[Math.floor(i % colors.length)];
    var alpha = 0.2 + Math.random() * 0.5;
    circle.alpha = alpha;
    circle.radius = r;
    circle.graphics.beginFill(color).drawCircle(0, 0, r);
    circle.x = x;
    circle.y = y;
    circles.push(circle);
    circle.movement = 'float';

    circle.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
      circle.graphics.clear().beginFill("red").drawRect(0, 0, 50, 60).endFill();
      stage.update(event);
    });

    stage.addChild(circle);

  }
}
```

I'm trying to add a mouseover listener on the little circles I create on the page, I hope that once I place the cursor on the circle, it becomes a rectangle. However, the rectangle always appear where some other circle exists rather than the circle I point to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are referencing a **mutable** variable inside of the closure. There are a couple of ways to solve that.

1) Either somehow reference the circle from the event variable inside of the nested function (if the event has support for that), or

2) Bind the value of the variable inside another function, e.g:

```js
function initCircles() {
    circles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var circle = new createjs.Shape();
        var r = 7;
        var x = window.innerWidth * Math.random();
        var y = window.innerHeight * Math.random();
        var color = colors[Math.floor(i % colors.length)];
        var alpha = 0.2 + Math.random() * 0.5;
        circle.alpha = alpha;
        circle.radius = r;
        circle.graphics.beginFill(color).drawCircle(0, 0, r);
        circle.x = x;
        circle.y = y;
        circles.push(circle);
        circle.movement = 'float';

        addEventListener(circle);

        stage.addChild(circle);
    }
    function addEventListener(circle) {
        circle.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
            circle.graphics.clear().beginFill("red").drawRect(0, 0, 50, 60).endFill();
            stage.update(event);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the right way until the command approach was added (answered in this thread) http://blog.createjs.com/new-command-approach-to-easeljs-graphics/

Comment: Thanks for your first suggestion, I refer to the circle like this:  event.target.graphics.clear().beginFill(event.target.color).drawCircle(0,0,15).endFill();

Answer (score 1):

Save your `beginFill` command, and change it later:

```
// your other code above
var fillCmd = circle.graphics.beginFill(color).command; // Note the .command at the end
circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, r);
// your other code below

// Later
fillCmd.style = "ff0000";
```

Here is [an article about it](http://blog.createjs.com/new-command-approach-to-easeljs-graphics/), and here are [the docs](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.Fill.html#property_style) -
Admittedly, this could be documented better. :)

Comment: thanks, i have solved this problem. But now l'm having trouble updating update text when mouse events happen. Do you know how to do it? Here is the link to this problem.